# Getting error "Uncaught Action failed: c:KYCQuote$controller$createAccount [action is not defined]" once clicked on save

Tags: lightning

Am getting error while clicked on save button.

KYC.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" controller="KYCQuote">
    <!--Style-->
    <aura:html tag="style">
          .slds-modal__container{
        height : auto;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 70rem;
        }
        .modal-body{
        height : 500px !important;
        max-height: 500px !important;
        }       
        .customFooter{
        display: inline !important;
        }
    </aura:html> 

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
    <aura:attribute name="quot" type="apttus_proposal_proposal__c"/>    
    <aura:attribute name="error" type="Boolean"/>

    <aura:attribute name="oppr" type="Opportunity__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="billingAddress" type="object[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="postingAddress" type="object[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="acv" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isModalOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="storeRadioValue" type="string"/>

    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String" default="Loading..."/>

     <aura:if isTrue="{!not(v.isModalOpen)}">    
    <div class="slds-scrollable slds-p-around_medium slds-text-heading_small" id="modal-content-id-1">
       <p style="height: 108px; word-wrap: break-word;">{!v.message}</p><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-modal__footer">
       <lightning:button class="slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.accept}" label="Accept" />
    </div>
    </aura:if>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isModalOpen}">

    <div class="modal-header slds-modal__header slds-size_1-of-1">
        <h4 class="title slds-text-heading_large">Quote/KYC</h4><!-- Quote/-->
    </div>

    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_x-small" ><!--style="max-height:400px; overflow:auto;"  -->
        <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="apttus_proposal_proposal__c" >
            <lightning:layout>
                <div class="demo-only" style="background:#FFFAF1">
                    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-title_bold"><b>Proposal Information</b></div>
                </div>  
            </lightning:layout>


            <!--Section 1-->
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">           
                  <lightning:messages />        
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Account__c" value="{!v.quot.Account__c}" required="true"/><!--value="{!v.quot.Account__c}{!v.accId}" -->
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="PriceList__c" required="true"/> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Opportunity__c" value="{!v.recordId}" required="true"/> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Primary_Contact__c" value="{!v.quot.Primary_Contact__c}" required="true"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="APTS_Quote_Type__c" value="{!v.oppr.OpportunityType__c}"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Selling_Country__c" required="true"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Order_Type__c" value="{!v.oppr.OpportunityType__c}" required="true"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Old_Owner__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Channel__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="X_code_Backup__c" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Xcode__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="X_Code_Account_Backup__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Quote_Total1__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Discount_Exception__c"/>
                  </div>
            </div>

            <!--Section 4-->
            <lightning:layout>
                <div class="demo-only" style="padding:0.5rem;background:#FFFAF1">
                    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-title_bold">Billing &amp; Posting Address</div>
                </div>  
            </lightning:layout>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" >            
                  <lightning:messages/>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="BillContact__c" value="{!v.quot.BillContact__c}" required="true"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="PostingContact__c" value="{!v.quot.PostingContact__c}" required="true"/>
                  </div>                 
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Special_Terms__c"/>
                  </div>
            </div>



            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <div><b>Please choose billing address</b></div><br/>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.billingAddress}" var="vb"> 
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <ui:inputRadio label="{!vb}" name="bc" change="{!c.onGroup}"/>
                    </div><br/>                   
                </aura:iteration>
            </div>

            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <div><b>Please choose posting address</b></div><br/>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.postingAddress}" var="vb"> 
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <ui:inputRadio label="{!vb}" name="pc"/>          
                    </div><br/>
                </aura:iteration>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                <lightning:button class="slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.createAccount}" label="Save" />

                <lightning:button class="slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.redirect}" label="Cancel" />
            </div>

        </lightning:recordEditForm>  
    </div>
    </ui:scrollerWrapper>
    </aura:if>
    <aura:html tag="style">
            .footer-to-be-fixed{
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
            }
            .cuf-content {
                padding: 0 0rem !important;
            }
            .slds-p-around--medium {
                padding: 0rem !important;
            }       
            .slds-modal__content{
                overflow-y:hidden !important;
                height:unset !important;
                max-height:unset !important;
            }

    </aura:html>
</aura:component>
```

KYCController.js

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) { 
       //component.set("v.isModalOpen",true); 
        var opportunityRecordVal;                                    
        var action = component.get("c.getRecord");        
        action.setParams({ recordId : component.get("v.recordId") });       
        action.setCallback(this, function(response1) {
        var state = response1.getState();
        //storing opportunity record in oppr variable
        component.set("v.oppr",response1.getReturnValue());              
        console.log('Account rec id in component'+"v.oppr");

            if(state === "SUCCESS"){                    
                opportunityRecordVal = response1.getReturnValue(); 
                var action1 = component.get("c.createnewcvr");                
                action1.setParams({ accId : opportunityRecordVal.Account__c });
                action1.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var state1 = response.getState();
                    if (state1 === "SUCCESS"){
                        if(response.getReturnValue() === 'Success KYC'){
                            var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
                            dismissActionPanel.fire();
                            var createRecordCVR = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
                            createRecordCVR.setParams({
                                "entityApiName": "Client_Validation_Request__c" ,
                                "defaultFieldValues":{
                                    "Contact__c" : opportunityRecordVal.Contact__c,
                                    "Account__c" : opportunityRecordVal.Account__c,
                                    "Contact_Email_Address__c" : opportunityRecordVal.Contact__r.Email,
                                    "Tel_Number__c" : opportunityRecordVal.Contact__r.Phone,    
                                    "GST_ID__c" : opportunityRecordVal.Account__r.GST_ID__c,
                                    "PAN_Number__c" : opportunityRecordVal.Account__r.PAN__c,
                                    "Account_Registration_Number__c" : opportunityRecordVal.Account__r.RegistrationNumber__c
                                  //"RecordTypeId" : Schema.SObjectType.Client_Validation_Request__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Default').getRecordTypeId()
                                }
                            }); 
                            createRecordCVR.fire();
                        }
                        else if(response.getReturnValue() === 'Success Quote'){
                            var action45 = component.get("c.getAccAddress");
                            action45.setParams({accId : opportunityRecordVal.Account__c })                             
                            action45.setCallback(this,function(response45){
                            var jsStr = action45.getReturnValue();
                            console.log(jsStr);
                            //var jsStrin = JSON.stringify(action45.getReturnValue());
                            component.set("v.billingAddress",jsStr[0].acc);
                            console.log(jsStr[0].acc);
                            component.set("v.postingAddress",jsStr[0].acc1);
                            console.log(jsStr[0].acc1);
                            var state45 = response45.getState(); 

                                if(state45 == "SUCCESS"){
                                    component.set("v.isModalOpen",true);
                                    var action1 = component.get("c.CreateNewQuote");
                                    action1.setParams({ recordId : component.get("v.recordId") });
                                    action1.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                                        var quote = response.getReturnValue();
                                        component.set("v.quot",response.getReturnValue());
                                    });                                
                                    $A.enqueueAction(action1);
                                }
                            });                                
                            $A.enqueueAction(action45);
                    }
                    else{
                            component.set("v.message","Error: "+response.getReturnValue());
                        }
                    }              
                });
                $A.enqueueAction(action1);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    },
    // accept button function to close quick action and reload the page
    accept : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
        location.reload();
    },
    createAccount : function(component, event,helper) {
            var newQuote = component.get("v.quot");
            console.log('Value of new quote');
            console.log(newQuote);
            var valueB = component.get("v.storeRadioValue");
            console.log('Value of selected value from billing');
            console.log(valueB);
            var action22 = component.get("c.saveAccount");
            action.setParams({ 
                "qu": newQuote,
                "billingAddr": valueB
            });
            action22.setCallback(this, function(a) {
                   var state = a.getState();
                    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                        var name = a.getReturnValue();
                    }
                });
            $A.enqueueAction(action22);
     },
     onGroup: function(component,event,helper){
            var getWhichBtn = event.getSource().get("v.label");
            component.set("v.storeRadioValue" , getWhichBtn);    
            alert(getWhichBtn);   
     },
     redirect: function (){
            $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
     }
})
```

KYCQuote.apxc

```
public class KYCQuote {

    @AuraEnabled
    Public static string createnewcvr(id accId){
        Account a = new Account();
        a = [select id,name,AccountStatus__c,Person_Account__c,ClientValidationCheck__c,RegistrationNumber__c,PostCountry__c,GST_ID__c,PAN__c,AccountID__c,Lead_Account_Status__c,(select id,lastname,Phone,Email,PrimarySalesContact__c from contacts where  PrimarySalesContact__c= true),(select id,name,Stage__c,Status__c,Account__r.ClientValidationCheck__c,Account__r.AccountStatus__c from Client_Validation_Requests__r) from Account where id =: accId];
        if(a.Lead_Account_Status__c != 'Active'){
            return 'Please Activate the Account ';
        }
        else if(a.contacts.size()>0){
            for(contact kon : a.contacts){
                if(kon.email == null || kon.Email=='' || kon.Phone == null || kon.Phone==''){ 
                    return 'Please enter Email and Phone at Contact level '+kon.lastname; 
                } 
            }
        }
        else if(a.contacts.size() == 0){
            return 'Please select Atleast One Primary Sales Contact True  At '+a.AccountID__c; 
        }
        else{
            Return 'Success Quote';
        }
        return 'Success Quote';
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    Public static string createnewkyc(id accId){
        System.debug('I am inside CreateNewKYC method in an KYCquote apex class');
        Account a = new Account();
        a = [select id,name,AccountStatus__c,ShippingCountry,Person_Account__c,ClientValidationCheck__c,RegistrationNumber__c,PostCountry__c,GST_ID__c,PAN__c,AccountID__c,Lead_Account_Status__c,(select id,lastname,Phone,Email,PrimarySalesContact__c from contacts where  PrimarySalesContact__c= true),(select id,name,Stage__c,Status__c,Account__r.ClientValidationCheck__c,Account__r.AccountStatus__c from Client_Validation_Requests__r) from Account where id =: accId];
        if(a.Lead_Account_Status__c != 'Active'){
            return 'Please Activate the Account ';
        }  
         system.debug('EEEEEEEE  '+a.contacts.size());
        if(a.ShippingCountry == 'India' && a.Person_Account__c == false){
            if(a.contacts.size()>0){
                for(contact kon : a.contacts){
                    if(kon.email == null || kon.Email=='' || kon.Phone == null || kon.Phone==''){ 
                        return 'Please enter Email and Phone at Contact level '+kon.lastname; 
                    } 
                }
            }
            else{
                return 'Please select Atleast One Primary Sales Contact True  At '+a.AccountID__c; 
            }

            if(a.Client_Validation_Requests__r.size()>0 ){
                for(Client_Validation_Request__c cv : a.Client_Validation_Requests__r){
                    system.debug('CVR Status Account  '+cv.Account__r.ClientValidationCheck__c+'  CV Stage  '+cv.Stage__c +' Status Appro '+ cv.Status__c);
                    if(cv.Stage__c != 'Closed'){
                        //Changes as per parag request https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?tab=wm&ogbl#inbox/FMfcgxwDqnhfrSQWMtpjDRdwLGBwCwhM
                        return 'You have validation Request '+cv.name+' with stage '+cv.Stage__c;
                        //return 'Success Quote';
                    }
                    else if(cv.Account__r.ClientValidationCheck__c == false && cv.Stage__c =='Closed' && cv.Status__c =='Approved'){
                        return 'Success Quote';
                    } else if(cv.Account__r.AccountStatus__c == 'Lapsed Customer' && cv.Account__r.ClientValidationCheck__c == true && cv.Stage__c=='closed'){
                        return 'Success KYC';                                                               
                    }
                }
            }  else {
                Return 'Success KYC';
            }   
        }
        else{
            Return 'Success Quote';
        }
        return 'Error ';
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    Public static opportunity__c getRecord(id recordId){
        System.debug('i am inside getRecord method');
        opportunity__c opp = [select id,Name,Account__c,Account__r.Name,Account__r.Person_Account__c,OpportunityType__c,Contact__c,Contact__r.Name,Contact__r.Phone,Account__r.GST_ID__c,Account__r.RegistrationNumber__c,Account__r.PAN__c,Contact__r.Email,Account__r.Billing_City2__c,Account__r.Billing_City3__c,Account__r.Billing_Country2__c,Account__r.Billing_Country3__c,Account__r.Billing_State_Province2__c,Account__r.Billing_State_Province3__c,Account__r.Billing_Street2__c,Account__r.Billing_Street3__c,Account__r.Billing_Zip_Postal_Code2__c,Account__r.Billing_Zip_Postal_Code3__c,Account__r.Posting_City2__c,Account__r.Posting_City3__c,Account__r.Posting_Country2__c,Account__r.Posting_Country3__c,Account__r.Posting_State_Province2__c,Account__r.Posting_State_Province3__c,Account__r.Posting_Street2__c,Account__r.Posting_Street3__c,Account__r.Posting_Zip_Postal_Code2__c,Account__r.Posting_Zip_Postal_Code3__c from opportunity__c where id =: recordId];
        System.debug('Returning from get record-------------------> '+opp);
        return opp;
    } 

    @AuraEnabled
    Public static apttus_proposal_proposal__c CreateNewQuote(id recordId){
        System.debug('i am inside CreateNewQuote method ');
        opportunity__c oppr = [select id,Name,Account__c,Account__r.Name,Account__r.Person_Account__c,OpportunityType__c,Contact__c,Contact__r.Name,Contact__r.Phone,Account__r.GST_ID__c,Account__r.RegistrationNumber__c,Account__r.PAN__c,Contact__r.Email,Account__r.Billing_City2__c,Account__r.Billing_City3__c,Account__r.Billing_Country2__c,Account__r.Billing_Country3__c,Account__r.Billing_State_Province2__c,Account__r.Billing_State_Province3__c,Account__r.Billing_Street2__c,Account__r.Billing_Street3__c,Account__r.Billing_Zip_Postal_Code2__c,Account__r.Billing_Zip_Postal_Code3__c,Account__r.Posting_City2__c,Account__r.Posting_City3__c,Account__r.Posting_Country2__c,Account__r.Posting_Country3__c,Account__r.Posting_State_Province2__c,Account__r.Posting_State_Province3__c,Account__r.Posting_Street2__c,Account__r.Posting_Street3__c,Account__r.Posting_Zip_Postal_Code2__c,Account__r.Posting_Zip_Postal_Code3__c from opportunity__c where id =: recordId];
        apttus_proposal_proposal__c quo = new apttus_proposal_proposal__c();
        quo.Account__c = oppr.Account__c;
        quo.Opportunity__c = oppr.Id;
        quo.APTS_Quote_Type__c = oppr.OpportunityType__c;
        quo.Order_Type__c = oppr.OpportunityType__c;
        quo.Primary_Contact__c = oppr.Contact__c;
        quo.BillContact__c = oppr.Contact__c;
        quo.PostingContact__c = oppr.Contact__c;
        System.debug('Returning the value from createNewQuote method-------------> '+quo);
        return quo;
    } 

     @AuraEnabled
    Public static Account getAccountRecord(id recordId){
        System.debug('i am inside getAccountRecord method');
      /*Account acc = [select id,Name,Person_Account__c,GST_ID__c,RegistrationNumber__c,PAN__c,Billing_City2__c,Billing_City3__c,Billing_Country2__c,Billing_Country3__c,Billing_State_Province2__c,Billing_State_Province3__c,Billing_Street2__c,Billing_Street3__c,Billing_Zip_Postal_Code2__c,Billing_Zip_Postal_Code3__c,Posting_City2__c,Posting_City3__c,Posting_Country2__c,Posting_Country3__c,Posting_State_Province2__c,Posting_State_Province3__c,Posting_Street2__c,Posting_Street3__c,Posting_Zip_Postal_Code2__c,Posting_Zip_Postal_Code3__c,(select id,name from Opportunities where id=:recordId) from Account];*/       
        Account acc = [select id,Name,Person_Account__c,GST_ID__c,RegistrationNumber__c,PAN__c,Billing_City2__c,Billing_City3__c,Billing_Country2__c,Billing_Country3__c,Billing_State_Province2__c,Billing_State_Province3__c,Billing_Street2__c,Billing_Street3__c,Billing_Zip_Postal_Code2__c,Billing_Zip_Postal_Code3__c,Posting_City2__c,Posting_City3__c,Posting_Country2__c,Posting_Country3__c,Posting_State_Province2__c,Posting_State_Province3__c,Posting_Street2__c,Posting_Street3__c,Posting_Zip_Postal_Code2__c,Posting_Zip_Postal_Code3__c from Account where id=:recordId];
        System.debug('Returning the account value from createNewQuote method---------->'+acc);
        System.debug('Returns account related value from an apex class for it to be stored in the variable');
        System.debug('Displaying account with oppo');
        Account AccWithOppr = [select id,name,industry,type,(select id,name,stage__c from opportunities__r) from account limit 100];

        return acc;
    }

  @AuraEnabled
    Public static List<AccountWrapperClass.wrapAccount> getAccAddress(id accId){
        List<AccountWrapperClass.wrapAccount> los = new List<AccountWrapperClass.wrapAccount>();
        Account acc = [select id,Name,Person_Account__c,GST_ID__c,RegistrationNumber__c,PAN__c,Billing_City2__c,Billing_City3__c,Billing_Country2__c,Billing_Country3__c,Billing_State_Province2__c,Billing_State_Province3__c,Billing_Street2__c,Billing_Street3__c,Billing_Zip_Postal_Code2__c,Billing_Zip_Postal_Code3__c,Posting_City2__c,Posting_City3__c,Posting_Country2__c,Posting_Country3__c,Posting_State_Province2__c,Posting_State_Province3__c,Posting_Street2__c,Posting_Street3__c,Posting_Zip_Postal_Code2__c,Posting_Zip_Postal_Code3__c from Account where id=:accId];       
        System.debug('Returning the account value from AccAddress method'+acc);
        AccountWrapperClass aa = new AccountWrapperClass();
        los = (aa.AccountWrapperClass(acc.Id));
        system.debug('Account wrapper content------------->'+los);
        system.debug('Size of account wrapper items----->'+los.size());
        return los;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    Public static String saveAccount(apttus_proposal_proposal__c qu,String billingAddr){
       System.debug('Inside createAccount'+qu);
       System.debug('Address---->'+billingAddr); 
        insert qu;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 console.log(valueB);
            var action22 = component.get("c.saveAccount");
            action.setParams({ 
                "qu": newQuote,
                "billingAddr": valueB
            });
            action22.s
```

action.setParams, when in code you define action22

Comment: thanks for the correction. It solved my issue.